# How to optimized a created hash in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization

Can I have some suggestion on how to optimize my query? So I have a query on a joined table and then recreated a new hash based on their status.

this is my controller code.

```
def index

        # create an empty hash for dynamic data
        @status_based_data = {}
        # get all workorder product
        @q = Product.ransack(params[:q])
        # loop all workorder product
        @q.result.each do |data|

          # check status if its a key in stat_based_data
        if !@status_based_data[data.status]
           # if not created make that a key with a value of an empty array 
          @status_based_data[data.status] = []
          # push whole data as a value
          @status_based_data[data.status].push(data)
        else
          # if status key is created just push the data
          @status_based_data[data.status].push(data)
     end

  end

end
```

View code:

```
<div>
  <% @status_based_data.each do |key, value| %>

    <h3><%= key %></h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered admin-report">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Status_id</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <% value.each do |val|%>
          <tr>
            <td> <%=val.id%> </td>
            <td> <%=val.status%> </td>
          </tr>
        <%end%>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

my view has an `O(n^2)` can you suggest another way of how I can approach this efficiently?

thank you.

Comment: can you show your products schema and the expected data format ?

Comment: the whole logic of creating a hash and grouping by the `status` can be simplified to `@status_based_data = @q.result.group_by(&:status)`. -- About the efficiency problem, I suggest using the DB to do the grouping

Comment: @Subash this table will have IDs, name, and status that's it.

Comment: @MrYoshiji ohh. I didn't know that about DB. so lets say i have a status of pending, complete, and cancelled, then on the DB layer it will group by itself even its nested?

Comment: What is ransack and result?

Comment: @MikeHeft its a gem for searching data. nothing much.